# OpenSemaphore Success but Access Denied - WinAPI

Tags: multithreading, winapi, access-denied

in the main Thread I Creat Semaphoer like that

```
My_Semaphore =  CreateSemaphore(NULL,0,MAX_SEM_COUNT,name);
```

and in the child-thread open it like that

```
   Test = OpenSemaphore(SYNCHRONIZE, TRUE, name);
```

GetlastError return 0, which mean the semaphore was successfully opened , but when I try to Release it

```
ReleaseSemaphore(name, MAX_SEM_COUNT, NUUL);
```

GetlastError return 5 (Access Denied).

but if instead-of, Open the semaphore by "OpenSemaphore" Function , I open it by calling "CreatSemaphore" (again in the child-thread) it's work fine and no Access Denied,

what's wrong in my code?

Comment: Do not ever call `GetLastError` unless instructed to. [`ReleaseSemaphore`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685071.aspx) tells you how to test for success/failure and when to call `GetLastError`.

Comment: What is the return value you get from OpenSemaphore? You should not use GetLastError unless the OpenSemaphore call returns NULL.

Comment: OpenSemaphore, gives me Handle to the Semaphore, but can't release it!

Comment: SYNCHRONIZE access does not include permission to call ReleaseSemaphore.

Comment: @RaymondChen, you right thnaks! , but how should I use OpenSemaphore and ReleaseSemaphore at once?

Comment: Read the documentation for OpenSemaphore. dwDesiredAccess valid values are given in [Synchronization Object Security and Access Rights](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686670(v=vs.85).aspx). Or you could start with ReleaseSemaphore which says what access is required to for ReleaseSemaphore to succeed.

Comment: @RaymondChen, thanks it's works! , it's should be opened with "SEMAPHORE_MODIFY_STATE"

Answer (score 0):

lpSemaphoreAttributes [in, optional]
A pointer to a SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES structure. If this parameter is NULL, the handle cannot be inherited by child processes.
The lpSecurityDescriptor member of the structure specifies a security descriptor for the new semaphore. If this parameter is NULL, the semaphore gets a default security descriptor. The ACLs in the default security descriptor for a semaphore come from the primary or impersonation token of the creator; from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438(v=vs.85).aspx
For latest version of Windows just use CreateSemaphore

Comment: Your answer is poorly formatted, and mostly copy-paste from the documentation, but your last sentence "just use CreateSemaphore()" solved my problem. If you improve your answer, I will give you my upvote.